# How do "driver scanner" applications work?

Tags: drivers, scam

For example, how does "Driver Scanner" from [uniblue](http://www.uniblue.com) work?
I mean, I know it's some kind of scam, but they need to provide some kind of service, after people pay for this app. So how does the full version work? Does it really improve anything, or is it a trick, like running windows update?

Comment: Windows update is just a trick? Are you trying to provoke an argument?

Comment: Go easy on the coffee, John: read it again, but more slowly this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every PCI device (and USB device) has a unique 'Vendor ID' and 'device ID', you can make a database with those unique numbers against known working drivers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space

Most of the 'free download' websites are just desperate for eye-balls and traffic to come along and click on the page adverts, so they tend to be a huge waste of space.

Comment: so dirver scanner has a database with VID, PID and urls to working drivers?

Comment: More or less, throw the OS in the mix and you've got it.

Comment: Correct. they probably bought the database in (from various big vendors, i.e. Intel, AMD, VIA, Broadcom, etc...), and sell the convenience to consumers and amateur PC technicians.

Comment: @TiZon: "throw the OS in the mix" -- what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well, to make sure you get the right driver they use 3 parameters: VID, PID and OS.